# Ajuda na criação de cadastro em Python

Tags: python, programação-funcional

Sou iniciante na área de programação, fiz um curso de python, e agora estou fortificando minha base fazendo alguns projetos.
Estou no desenvolvimento de um projeto voltado a um sistema simples de python para um gerenciamento de uma mercearia.
Dividi este sistema em 3 partes, uma delas é a área de gerenciamento de produtos, oque eu queria era criar uma lista de produtos que além de ter o nome e preço do produto, possa ser modificada a qualquer hora, porém, sempre que eu inicio os sistema a lista fica sem nada que eu coloquei, e não consigo pensar em uma forma de colocar um preço juntamente com um item, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço!!

```
lista_de_itens_v = list()

print("================================================================= Olá, Bem vindo a Mercearia! =========================================================================\n")
print("OQUE DESEJA FAZER?")
print("=================================")
print("REMOVER/ADICONAR UM ITEM - Digite 1\nVER ESTOQUES - Digite 2\nVER QUANTIDADE ESPECÍFICA DE UM PRODUTO - Digite 3")
print("=================================")

resposta_principal = int(input("Insira aqui o número..."))

# REMOVER/ADICONAR UM ITEM #

if resposta_principal == 1:
    print("Se você deseja adicionar um item, digite '1', se deseja remover um item digite '2'")
    resposta_1_ou_2 = int(input("Insira aqui sua resposta...\n"))
    if resposta_1_ou_2 == 1:
        print("Agora, escreva o nome do produto que deseja adicionar abaixo\n...")
        produto_add = input("Insira aqui...")
        lista_de_itens_v.append(produto_add)
        
    elif resposta_1_ou_2 == 2:
        print("Agora, escreva o nome do produto que deseja remover abaixo\n...")
        produto_rem = input("Insira aqui...")
        lista_de_itens.remove(produto_rem)
        
    else:
        print("Caractere inválido")
        

# VER ESTOQUES #

if resposta_principal == 2:
    print(lista_de_itens)

# VER QUANTIDADE ESPECÍFICA DE UM PRODUTO #

if resposta_principal == 3:
    item = input("insira aqui o nome do produto que você desejar ver a quantidade no estoque...")
    qnt = lista_de_itens.count(item)
    print(qnt)
    
if (resposta_principal != 1) and (resposta_principal != 2) and (resposta_principal != 3):
    print("Resposta inválida!")
```

Comment: um solução é usar o `open()` com a opção `read` salvando em csv ou se preferir em txt. é uma boa base para continuar.

Comment: Já pensou em usar um banco de dados https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é criar métodos helpers para auxiliar na leitura a escrita das informações lidas.

Utilizando a função [open](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) do Python, ela é a responsável por fazer a leitura e escrita em um sistema de arquivos.

A documentação mostra que a função open em seu segundo parâmetro (mode) é uma string opcional que especifica o modo no qual o arquivo é aberto. O valor padrão é 'r', que significa abrir para leitura em modo texto.
Outros valores comuns são 'w' para escrever (truncando o arquivo se ele já existe), 'x' para criação exclusiva e 'a' para fazer o append (o qual em alguns sistemas Unix, significa que todas as escritas anexam ao final do arquivo independentemente da posição de busca atual). No modo texto, se encoding não for especificada, a codificação usada depende da plataforma: `locale.getencoding()` é chamada para obter a codificação da localidade atual (Para ler e escrever bytes diretamente, use o modo binário e não especifique encoding). Os modos disponíveis são:

| Caractere | Significado |
| --- | --- |
| 'r' | abre para leitura (padrão) |
| 'w' | abre para escrita, truncando o arquivo primeiro (removendo tudo o que estiver contido no mesmo) |
| 'x' | abre para criação exclusiva, falhando caso o arquivo exista |
| 'a' | abre para escrita, anexando ao final do arquivo caso o mesmo exista |
| 'b' | modo binário |
| 't' | modo texto (padrão) |
| '+' | aberto para atualização (leitura e escrita) |

Desta forma uma implementação possível seria uma rotina para leitura, e outra para escrita dos dados, segue o exemplo concreto:

```
def ler_dados_arquivo():
    try:
        f = open('data', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
        saida = []
        for d in f.readlines():
            saida.append(d)
        f.close()
        return saida
    except:
        return []

def gravar_dados_arquivo(dados):
    try:
        f = open('data', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
        for d in dados:
            f.write(d)
            f.write('\n')
    except:
        print('Não foi possível gravar em arquivo')
```

Então ao iniciar o seu programa basta fazer a leitura dos dados, e depois seguir o fluxo de uso do sistema, adicionando um novo produto ou removendo um produto.

Coloco em destaque apenas o código que será necessário modificar, para ler o arquivo sempre ao iniciar a aplicação e após a rotina de inserção / remoção de itens:

```
 lista_de_itens_v = ler_dados_arquivo ()
 #...
 if resposta_1_ou_2 == 1:
    print("Agora, escreva o nome do produto que deseja adicionar abaixo\n...")
    produto_add = input("Insira aqui...")
    lista_de_itens_v.append(produto_add)
    gravar_dados_arquivo(lista_de_itens_v)
    
 elif resposta_1_ou_2 == 2:
    print("Agora, escreva o nome do produto que deseja remover abaixo\n...")
    produto_rem = input("Insira aqui...")
    try:
        lista_de_itens_v.remove(produto_rem)
        gravar_dados_arquivo(lista_de_itens_v)
    except ValueError:
        print('Item não encontrado na lista')
```

Repare que na rotina de remoção de um item da lista eu adicionei um bloco try... catch para que seja possível tratar um caso de erro em que o item a ser removido não faz parte da lista.

[Código completo para consulta](https://gist.github.com/danizavtz/d8688538af63ff3d71afbc16da6193a4)

Comment: Muito obrigado, você me ajudou demais!! Com estes códigos você me deu muitas ideias, valeu mesmo.

Comment: uma coisa, na hora da remoção de produto não está funcionando, consegue me ajudar? de qualquer jeito que escrever o nome do produto aparece como produto não encontrado